# Deserialize different element tags into one object class?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the this form of xml

```
<Element attributeX="X" attributeY="Y"> 
  <SubElement attributeX="X" attributeZ="Z"/>
</Element>
<Element attributeX="X" attributeY="Y"> 
  <SubElement attributeX="X" attributeZ="Z"/>
  <Element attributeX="X" attributeY="Y">
    <SubElement attributeX="X" attributeZ="Z"/>
  </Element>
</Element>
```

but in the code I have one object class for "Element" and "SubElement" with attributes "attributeY" "attributeX" and "attributeZ", I cannot find a way to do the deserialisation of the XML ?

Ia wan to add that y exmaple is different from the links you gave me. In fact here is the class that I have in my code

```
public class Element
{
  public type1 attributeX;
  public type1 attributeY;
  public type1 attributeZ;

  public observableCollection<Element> Elements;
}
```

and in the xml file I have different tags : * SubElement when I have attributeZ *Element when I have attributeY

So when oing the desrialisation "Element" and "subElement" should have the same class type "Element"

Answer (score 1):

The following example might be a good start on your journey:

```
public class Element
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public type1 attributeX { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public type1 attributeY { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool attributeYSpecified { get { return attributeY != null; } set { } }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public type1 attributeZ { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool attributeZSpecified { get { return attributeZ != null; } set { } }

    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ElementTypes")]
    [XmlElement("Element", typeof(Element))]
    [XmlElement("SubElement", typeof(Element))]
    public Element[] Elements { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ElementType[] ElementTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return Elements
                .Select(el => (el.attributeYSpecified && !el.attributeZSpecified) ?
                              ElementType.Element :
                              (!el.attributeYSpecified && el.attributeZSpecified) ?
                              ElementType.SubElement :
                              ElementType.None)
                .ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
}

public enum ElementType
{
    None,
    Element,
    SubElement
}
```

Note that I defined each `*Specified` property to look for a `null` value, but if `type1` is a value type, you may need to keep them as simple properties and manually check them after deserialization and set them for proper serialization.

The `None` enumeration value is on purpose, to make serialization fail when things look weird.  However, if you have some sensible default that can have both Y and Z attributes, you may remove it.

Comment: thnk you very much Paulo, but I a missing a detail : in  fact I am using obsservablecollections to bind these information, so Haw cana I change this ?

Comment: I tried that, it seems `XmlSerializer` requires an array for the choice dispatcher property/field, and it generates buggy code if the actual property/field is not an array itself, because it uses `.Length` instead of checking if it's an `ICollection` and using `.Count` in that  case.  It does so in other cases, so maybe open an issue with Microsoft.

Comment: In the mean time, you'd better handle this yourself, by having a proxy property or by implementing `IXmlSerializable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this type of situation I suggest you take a look at the following :
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This will allow you to manually specific the serialization and serialization algorithm.

You may also use this if its only for xml:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is an example of how to implement the latter :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly